# Can't load http api to rdbms using stambia S19

Tags: etl, rdbms

[here is the mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8d4t.png)
[here is the metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8WY6.png)
While creating the metadata (a very simple one), the reverse works just fine
but whene executing the process (or mapping) i get many errors, each time i try to fix an error, a new one apears... Which got me thinkin that the example found in the docs isn't good for me and my metadata needs to be recreated differently and that's where i need help...
Here is my last error :
[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKN1d.png)

The way i see it, it's a simple json response to be loaded into a database that every ETL shoold be able to do...

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)